# How to provide routes dynamically at bootstrap?

Tags: angular2-routing

How can I provide a service to a RouterModule so that I can dynamically inject routes based on some parameter?

Mind you, this parameter is also dynamic (it comes from an api call before bootstrapping).

I do realize that by using RouterModule.forRoot (which is a static function) I am quite constrained with injecting services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the ROUTES token with a function that produces the routes configuration and takes that parameter. Also, you need to provide that parameter.

```js
import {ROUTES} from '@angular/router/src/router_config_loader';
[...]
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([])] // Empty on purpose
providers: [
  SomeParamForTheFunction,
  {provide: ROUTES, 
   multi: true, 
   useFactory: routesFunction, 
   deps: [SomeParamForTheFunction]},
]
```

How you provide that param is up to you. You could use another factory for it.

**UPDATE**: Since the routing configuration is now dynamic, you have to provide also an entryComponents property with all the components required for initial page load.

Comment: Thanks @Ruben, that solution has been a lifesaver for me too :)

Comment: I am trying to implement this and found your answer. But I'm not clear on the structure of the `routesFunction`. I tried returning an array of Route objects and got this error, _"Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler (position 15:22 in the original .ts file)"_  
  
  
`export function loadRouterMap(init: ScaffHelperService) { return init.getRouteMap(); }`

Comment: That is probably something unrelated to routing. Here is a fork of the standard angular plnkr example showing how it works: https://plnkr.co/edit/kt73vzz8HCSMcj85lQYH?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

In order to provide the `entryComponents` dynamically, you can make the following amendment to the code @Ruben provided:

```
import {ROUTES} from '@angular/router/src/router_config_loader';
import {ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS} from '@angular/core';
[...]
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([])] // Empty on purpose
providers: [
  SomeParamForTheFunction,
  {provide: ROUTES, 
    multi: true, 
    useFactory: routesFunction, 
    deps: [SomeParamForTheFunction]
  },
  {
    provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
    useValue: routes, // just write the original routes
    multi: true
  }
]
```

This way, you won't need to declare `entryComponents` once if they're declared at the module `declarations`.